# Reset file data

Tags: java, io

I need to write player data to a file and read it and whenever it saves, edit the data. I'm not too good with File I/O but here's what I have.

```
public class DirectoryMaker {


    static BufferedWriter bw;
    static int lvl = 1;
    static int hp = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        FileWriter fw;



        File dir = new File("c:\\MyFile\\b\\stuff");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            if (dir.mkdirs()) {
                System.out.println("Directory is created!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
            }

        }




        String fileName="hi";
        File tagFile=new File(dir,fileName+".txt");
        if(!tagFile.exists()){
        try {



            fw = new FileWriter(tagFile.getAbsoluteFile());
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("LEVEL: " + lvl + "\n");


            tagFile.createNewFile();
            bw.close();



        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        }


        Scanner s = new Scanner(tagFile);
        while(s.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(s.nextLine());

        }
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Using this code, how can I update the lvl int in the file when It changes. After having this int updated I need to add others and read them.

Comment: Why is rewriting the whole file not an option?

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing data in a file as text, I'd highly suggest YAML, it formats your data nicely, and makes it easy to retrieve. Another alternative is a JSON file, but I'm not nearly as familiar with JSON. Here is a commonly used YAML library: https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/ It's pretty simple to use:

```
File f = ...;
String s = "Me";
Yaml y = new Yaml();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
y.dump(Map.Entry<"Name",s>, writer);
writer.Close();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
Map map = (Map) yaml.load(f); //Loads whole document
String name = map.get("Name"); //Find the String with the key "Name"
in.Close();
```

There are probably some improvements to be made, but this is mostly just to give you an idea of functionality.